# How to retrieve the last table cell within each table row using the .each() and .last() methods?

Tags: jquery, each, children

How can I retrieve a jQuery object containing the last table cells of each row **using the .each() and the .last() methods**?

I tried the following code, but it's returning me all the table rows and not table cells, and I *really* can't figure out what is wrong with it.

```
const $lastCells = $('tr').each((i, element) =>
  $(element).children().last()
);
console.log($lastCells);
```

**- UPDATE -**
After scratching my head for a while I found the error in my reasoning: I was thinking you could return the operations inside an `.each()` method, but as [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) pointed out (thank you!), the `.each()` method always returns the object on which it is called. If I want to return a new object with the last cells of each row I need to use the `.map()` method instead, for example:

```
const $lastCells = $('tr').map((i, element) =>
  $(element).children().last()[0]
);
console.log($lastCells);
```

Comment: `$('tr td:last-child').each()`

Comment: You're getting the rows because you're selecting the `tr`. The `each()` call will return the element(s) it was called on, not the ones you select in the handler logic.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5scgLna9/ - `$('tr td:last-child').each(function() { console.log($(this).html())})` and
`$('tr').each(function() { console.log($("td",this).last().html())})` have same output, but I would prefer the first

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the book exercise I'm trying to solve specifically asks me to use "the `.last()` method within each row (using `.each()` to loop over the rows)", so even if did manage to solve the problem using both the `:last-child` and `:nth-child()` pseudo-classes, I am struggling to find the solution using the `.last()` and `.each()` methods.

Comment: I just showed you in my previous comment - but you forgot to tell us this is homework

Comment: It's not homework, I'm just reading the Learning jQuery 3 book and this is one of the chapter exercises. Thank you, I just went through your previous comment and it does do what I'm looking for... I didn't know you could write a selector like `$("td",this)`! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each tr and get the last td with :last

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var lasttd=  $(this).find(':last-child')
  //your code
});
```

Comment: `table:first` is useles since the OP didn't mention that he wants the first table or if there are several tables.

Comment: Oh you're right, edited :)

Comment: And no need to loop over tr, you can loop over tr td:last-child as I already commented